# $N$-dimensional optimization problem with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

There is an open $N$-dimensional optimization problem in engineering; however, to guarantee a certain result a second constraint has to be added to it. The problem formulation is:
$$ \max_{\bar{x}} \sum_{i=1}^N \ln\left(1+\frac{c_0h_ix_i}{c_1+y_{i}x_{i-1}h_{i-1}+z_ix_{i+1}h_{i+1}}\right) $$
subject to:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \le X_0 $$
$$0\le x_i\le x_i^{\max} \quad \forall i$$
Apart from $\bar{x}=[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N]$, which is the vector containing variables of optimization,  all other terms are constants, $c_0$, $c_1$, $X_0$, $\bar{y}=[y_1,y_2,\dots,y_N], \bar{z}=[z_1,z_2,\dots,z_N], \bar{h}=[h_1,h_2,\dots,h_N]$ and $\overline{x^{\max}}=[x_1^{\max},x_2^{\max},\dots,x_N^{\max}]$.
I have basic knowledge of the method  of Lagrange multipliers and KKT conditions but this one is beyond my ability as an engineer and requires a specialized mathematician. I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Your definition of "one dimensional" must be different from mine. I'd call this $N$-dimensional.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I corrected it now

Comment: Are all $c,y,z,h$ parameters non-negative? Also, what are $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i+1}$ when $i=1$ and $i=N$ respectively?